# JPA XML Query File

Tags: jpa, toplink

I would like to include all named queries in a separate XML file and use it in persistence. How can I accomplish the same?

I am using Toplink JPA in a JSF-Web application. Actually, I am not able to get the directory/file structure to use.

I tried to use `<mapping-file>` in `persistence.xml` and tried to place the query file in several locations. Every time I am getting exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [define named query in orm.xml with jpa and hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373369/define-named-query-in-orm-xml-with-jpa-and-hibernate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either place to XML file queries that later will be executed by

```
 EntityManager.createQuey(query)
```

where query is provided by XML.

Or, the better way(!), use already existing possibility to declare JPA parts in mapping XML (example see [define named query in orm.xml with jpa and hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373369/define-named-query-in-orm-xml-with-jpa-and-hibernate)). In the last case you can even use:

```
 EntityManager.createNamedQuery(queryName)
```