# Manage Hibernate Generator Sequence

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle10g

I need help related to *Hibernate Generator Sequence*.

Is it possible to manage with Hibernate java class a sequence defined in DB (Oracle) mapped by **hibernate hbm** file ?

I mean, update the sequence manually from java mapped class to generate a composite sequence.

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean when you say "update the sequence"? Update is not applicable to sequences, at least not in Oracle.

Comment: Sorry, update the sequence, I mean to use the sequence (next, current, etc... ) defined in oracle DB via hibernate. It's possible to map a sequence (annotations, hbm.xml... ), without any relation to an POJO (in hibernate cfg file for example), and use it wherever I need ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a sequence via Hibernate you can use a named query. For example, consider following links: [define named query in orm.xml with jpa and hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373369/define-named-query-in-orm-xml-with-jpa-and-hibernate) and http://www.coderanch.com/t/218082/ORM/java/Getting-sequence-hibernate .

Comment: hi!
I've tried this workaround and it worked as I want.

This is what I finally did:

1. Create de query in *.hbm.xml mapping file from Entity:

`<sql-query name="nextSequenceValue">
 <![CDATA[
 SELECT sec_new_sequence.nextVal FROM dual
 ]]>
</sql-query>`

2. Execute the query in java code: 

`Query query = getSession().getNamedQuery("nextSequenceValue");`

It control the sequence as a wrapper to manage in java.

Thanks!