# How do I create Named Queries in a Separate file

Tags: java, jpa, named-query

I need to keep the all the named queries in a separate file. For example

```
@javax.persistence.NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e")})

public class AllNamedQueries {

}
```

Now that much in itself causes an Error "Named queries can only be defined in Entity or MappedSuperClass class".

How do I create Named Queries in a Separate file? By separate I mean files other than entity file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `orm.xml` that allows you to define JPA mappings in XML. This approach is equivalent and overrides annotations.

Example based on [define named query in orm.xml with jpa and hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373369):

```
<entity class="com.example.Employee">
    <table name="Employee.findAll" />
    <named-query name="findAll">
        <query><![CDATA[
          SELECT e
          FROM Employee e
        ]]></query>
    </named-query>
</entity>
```

Comment: I'm using OpenJPA, not hibernate.

Comment: What has Hibernate got to do with anything? This is JPA, as per the spec.

Comment: @SQC: `orm.xml` is a JPA standard descriptor: *define **JPA** mappings in XML* - works in every JPA provider. See: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.0/apache-openjpa-1.0.0/docs/manual/jpa_overview_persistence.html

Comment: Thanks guys, I thought OpenJPA doesn't use one