# How to use XML configuration for named queries in Spring data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

As per the [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/snapshot-site/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries) we can specify named queries in an XML. But it does not tell how to use it in the code. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
say you have defined the `Named Query` as `application.myquery` in XML file.
```

In service/dao layer

```
List results = em.createNamedQuery("application.myquery")
    .setParameter("username", "blah")
    .setParameter("password","blahblahblah")
    .getResultList();
```

The `orm` file need to be included inside `persistence.xml` and  the same should reside at `META-INF/persistence.xml`.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">

  <persistence-unit name="myUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes/>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Refer [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch14s06.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried this out but getting the error that the named query not found. Looks like the XML file is not getting loaded. Where should XML file reside? I tried it in META-INF

Answer (score 3):

As is mentioned by the lead developer of Spring Data JPA [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734149/namedquery-override-findall-in-spring-data-rest-jparepository), all you need to do (if you are using a version newer or equal to Spring Data JPA 1.5 - I tested with 1.6.1.RELEASE) is add a method in the repository with the same name as the query.

For example you could have code like:

```
    @Entity
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByLastname", query="select u from User u where u.lastname = ?1")
    public class User {
       //whatever
    }
```

If you don't want to use annotations but prefer XML instead, you need to add

```
<named-query name="User.findByLastname">
  <query>select u from User u where u.lastname = ?1</query>
</named-query>
```

to `orm.xml` like is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8407829/2504224)

Finally the repository would look like

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query
  List<User> findByLastname(String lastname);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Where should I place the XML file?

Answer (score 1):

META-INF/orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <named-query name="Role.findByCond">
        <query>from Role where rid = ?1 and rname = ?2</query>
    </named-query>

</entity-mappings>
```

RoleRepository.java

```
@Query
List<Role> findByCond(String rid, String rname);
```