# Externalize query in spring boot application

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using `spring-boot 1.5.6 RELEASE`. I want to do a basic thing, move my queries from the `@Query` annotation in the repository to any xml file.

After some reading, I figured out that we can use `orm.xml` or `jpa-named-queries.properties` to write my custom query.

I don't understand the file structure as to where these XML files have to be present. And I don't have a `META-INF` folder in my project.

Example:

POJO Class:

```
@Entity
public Class Customer {

private int id;
private String name;

// getters and setters
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Customer,Integer> {

// this query I need from an external xml file as it might be quite complex in terms of joins
@Query("Select cust from Customers cust")
public List<Customer> findAllCustomers();

}
```

EDIT: Referred to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931248/how-to-use-xml-configuration-for-named-queries-in-spring-data-jpa). I need to know where these files (`orm.xml` and `persistence.xml`) need to be stored as I don't have a `META-INF` folder.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use XML configuration for named queries in Spring data JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931248/how-to-use-xml-configuration-for-named-queries-in-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: Yes, I have come across this question. But like I mentioned, I do not have a `META-INF` folder, and I am very much confused as to where these `properties/ xml` files have to be stored. @Todd

Comment: Please check github example at https://github.com/eclipse/examples/tree/master/jpa/employee.dynamic/src/main/resources/META-INF and http://webdev.jhuep.com/~jcs/ejava-javaee/coursedocs/605-784-site/docs/content/html/hibernate-migration-orm.html, if META-INF is not present then you have to create it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create `META-INF` inside `resources` folder . Now create `jpa-named-queries.properties` file inside that `META-INF` folder.

Write your query inside this properties file like this:

`Customer.findAllCustomerByNamedQuery=Select c from Customer c`

Where `Customer` denote name of entity class and `findAllCustomerByNamedQuery` is the query name

In your customer repository write this to call your query written in properties file:

`List<Customer> findAllCustomerByNamedQuery();`

Comment: Thanks! creating META-INF manually worked for me! Is there any reason why it won't be created along with files like application.properties?

Comment: i don't know the reason for that

Comment: THANK YOU! Exactly what is was looking for. Where did you find these info?

Comment: @SebastianDuque thanks for you comment . I found these infos from spring-data-example repository , Here is the link :https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples

Comment: Note that this jpa-named-queries.properties is not being syntax-highlighted by Intellij IDEA

Comment: its not loading for me with spring boot version 2.5.1

Comment: @SPS Can you check the logs . Are you getting any warning or error ?

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility to use named queries from [spring data jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries).

```
 <named-query name="MyData.ultimateFind">
    <query>select d from MyData d where d.column3 = ?1</query>
 </named-query>
```

To bind it with repository method, your repository class can look like this:

```
public interface MyDataRepository extends JpaRepository<MyData, Long> {
  List<User> ultimateFind(String dataForColumn3);   
}
```

Other approach (more sexy, but as of now, [having problem with java 17](https://github.com/gasparbarancelli/spring-native-query/issues/46)) is to use [spring-native-query](https://gasparbarancelli.github.io/spring-native-query/), which reads sql filed from resources. It allows you to have custom repository type with nice bindings directly to sql files (also with conditional parts of sql if needed.).