# How to Keep @Query in properties file and access these queries in JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data and jpaRepository for interacting with DB.

```
    public interface TelevisionSourceRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTelevisionSource, Long> {

        @Query("select new com.tivo.extract.config.dto.SourceListDTO(s.SourceId, s.SourceName, t.TvsourceLongName) from MyTelevisionSource t join fetch RCMSource s ON s.SourceId = t.SourceId")
        List<SourceListDTO> findSourceList(Pageable pageable);
    }
```

I want to keep the query in properties file and want to use those query.

I tried with

```
    @PropertySource("classpath:/Query.properties")


    @Value("${RCM.findSourceList}")
        List<SourceListDTO> findSourceList(Pageable pageable);
```

but its not working, any other way is there

Comment: Why are using `@Value` annotation instead of `@Query` annotation?

Comment: you are telling the below way

@Query("@Value("${RCM.findSourceList}")")

Comment: nope, test it with `@Query("${RCM.findSourceList}")`.

Comment: i have tried this way also, it will give $ token error

Comment: Try this `@Query("#{RCM.findSourceList}")` or `@Query("#{#RCM.findSourceList}")`.

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '#' [#{#RCM.findSourceList}]

Comment: One suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060590/externalize-query-in-spring-boot-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you declare a string with @Value. and put the string in @Query value.
in `application.properties`

```
spring.queries.status-query=SELECT * FROM mydb.project ORDER BY purchase_order ASC,customer_name ASC
```

and in your class

```java
@Value("${spring.queries.status-query}")
    String status_query="0";


@Query(value = status_query,nativeQuery = true)
    List<project> findAllSorted();
```

Comment: Do you know that annotation parameters must be constant? And this way it is not.