# How to write named queries with xml in Hibernate/JPA?

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am able to use Named Query using annotations without any issues. But when I try to switch to **orm.xml** files to externalize my application couldn't find my named query which is in `User.orm.xml` file under classpath **META-INF** directory. The full path of my `User.orm.xml` file is `src\main\resources\META-INF\User.orm.xml` When I try to run the query I get the following exception,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name [READ_ALL_USERS]
[artifact:mvn]  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.buildQueryFromName(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:788)
```

My **`persistence.xml`** which is under `src/main/resources/META-INF` looks like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="webPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.spring.model.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And my **`User.orm.xml`** file has the following named-query,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">  
    <named-query name="READ_ALL_USERS">
        <query>SELECT user from com.spring.User user</query>
    </named-query>
</entity-mappings>
```

I looked upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373369/define-named-query-in-orm-xml-with-jpa-and-hibernate) which suggests to keep the orm.xml file where the model class exists. But it doesn't work for me. What is the problem in the above code.

I've also included the mapping the User.orm.xml file in my persistence.xml which is already in my classpath under META-INF directory. I've tried the following file mappings but none of them detects my xml file,

```
<mapping-file>User.orm.xml</mapping-file>

<mapping-file>/META-INF/User.orm.xml</mapping-file>

<mapping-file>classpath:User.orm.xml</mapping-file>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add a `<mapping-file>` element inside the `<persistence-unit>` element.

Example: 
`<persistence-unit>
<mapping-file>User.orm.xml</mapping-file>
</persistence-unit>`

Source: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html

Comment: Yes. I've already tried that. I included the User.orm.xml in the class path and also in the persistence file. But it's not recognized. Any other ideas?

Comment: In the persistence.xml you need use the full path of the orm.xml: <mapping-file>com/mycompany/product/package/orm.xml</mapping-file>